# Whats's the electronic component in this picture called?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

[image]

The photo is taken from an Acer Monitor's power board. The monitor model is K242HL and the power board part serial is 4H.220V2.A17. As an electronics beginner and being of curiousity, I tried to identify each electronic component on this broken circuit board.

Comment: It's hard to Identify components by a picture since many many components share the same "package", so sometimes you infer what is what based not only on package but also on where it's located in the board and what it would make sense to be. for reference here you can see a bunch of standard packages, there could be pretty much anything in them since a package is not necessarily linked to any particular circuit that should be inside it. In fact you can usually find a particular component in a variety of packages.
https://cdn.sparkfun.com/assets/c/7/a/1/9/51e0633cce395f867b000000.jpg

Comment: Also it's very common for manufacturers to make it hard to reverse engineer their circuits as protection against the competition by erasing the part numbers and printing some internal code on them. so even if some chip is a really common out of the mill part internally you might find a code printed on it that you cant find in google.

Comment: Your question would be easier to answer with a clear **in focus** picture with more of the surrounding in place, **and or** a written description of the text on the part and the surround board.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

99% sure it's a 3.3V linear regulator. Clues:

- 33 marking on the package
- I (input), G (ground), O (output) markings on the PCB.

Potentially a part like [AZ1117CH2-3.3TRG1](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/AZ1117CH2-3-3TRG1/7352815), which has the same pinout:

[image]